# Return only the first parameter from stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, hana-sql-script

How can I make it possible to return only the first parameter from a stored procedure with multiple OUT-parameters?

**Overview of Parameters**

| Position | Parameter Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OUT |
| 2 | OUT |

So instead of create the CALL statement like this

```
CALL SCHEMA.PROC123(?, ?);
```

I try to do this

```
CALL SCHEMA.PROC123(?);
```

Answer (score 1):

OUT parameters in SQLScript are not optional. At the moment the only way to reach want you want to have, is, to create a wrapper procedure with only the one required OUT parameter.